Root relative path works like relative path
I have links on /en/ like <a href="/en/contact.html">Contact</a>
It works when I test, but I sometimes see in analytics report that a user first visits /en/ and then /en/en/contact.html which is 404 - not found. It seems that root relative path works like relative path for some users. How can it be possible?
Additional info:
1- There are only two links to contact.html, I checked both, no problem detected.
2- I have a redirecting root page, but I think it cannot affect the links on /en/ page.
3- The user profile is Headless Chrome, Windows 10, New York, same IP but visitor ids are different for each page, and page visiting times are like a human. What can it be?

Unless you can provide the link that causes it it will be hard to debug. In likelihood you have a relative link somewhere that a user is clicking. Maybe with the intent to navigate relatively inside a language folder, but accidentally including your language folder again? Paths have been such an old thing now, it would be incredibly surprising if a bug like this had been slipping through for the better part of 30 years now.

@somethinghere, I added info.

If it's not you and there's no real issues, it's probably a bot or script or scraper trying out some things to see what hits.
